# How to get string between bracket ] and [

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get text "STARTS WITH" from following string [DOC TEXT] STARTS WITH [foo] using regex. I have used following code for this.

```
String expertWhereClause = (String) formFields
                    .get(Constants.EXPERT_SEARCH_WHERECLAUSE);
            String delims = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
            String[] tokens = expertWhereClause.split(delims);
```

but am getting following string "[,  STARTS WITH ]". I just want "STARTS WITH".

Am new to regex, please help me out here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell us what language are you using (Have you tried getting the second matching group?)

Comment: Give Valid and Invalid Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
\]\s*([^\[]*?)\s*\[
```

You may need to escape the backslashes based on the language you are using.
Update: For Java, escape the backslashes

```
\\]\\s*([^\\[]*?)\\s*\\[
```

The desired text is captured in the first group.

Comment: Give me following errorInvalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Comment: @Kash, the language in question is java.

Comment: @Pradeep: try now. This will eliminate the spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Matcher` for this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\]([^\\[]*)\\[").matcher("[Hello]world[!!!]");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This code fragment [prints](http://ideone.com/aezuQ) `world` on ideone.

Note how I changed your regex to use `[^\\[]*` in place of `.*?`. [This improves efficiency](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance), which may be important for longer inputs.

Comment: He does not need the content inside the brackets. He needs the opposite.

Comment: @Kash Thanks for the note, this is now fixed.

Comment: +1, but can you explain why `[^\\[]*` is more efficient than `.*?`?

Comment: Let me try the above. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: @ColinD This is faster because it eliminates backtracking. I edited the answer to provide a link to a great post explaining the point.

Comment: Looks good to me there are some spaces as well which I need to remove to get an exact text

Comment: @Pradeep The easiest thing to do would be to use `trim()` on the Java end, otherwise your regular expression would get a lot more complicated (and it's not overly simple to begin with).

Comment: @Pradeep You could go back to the reluctant `.*?` expression to remove spaces. Here is a [link](http://ideone.com/RNPwL) that shows how.

Comment: Or you could use my answer to ignore spaces: `\\]\\s*?([^[]*?)\\s*?\\[`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I dont think you need to escape the "[" in the character set, right?

Comment: Yes i need to remove the character "[" or  "]". I just need the text STARTS WITH

Comment: @Kash I am pretty certain that you need to escape `[` even inside the expression: I got a runtime error without `\\`. Also the use of `[^[]*?` in place of `.*?` is not helpful, because you do allow `\\s` after it. Finally, `\\s*?` expressions do not need to be reluctant.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Thanks.. You are right. Edited my answer to reflect that. Removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Java then you can use this code:

```
String str = "[DOC TEXT] STARTS WITH [foo] ";
System.out.printf("<%s>%n", 
                    str.replaceAll("^[^\\]]+\\]\\s*([^\\[]+?)\\s*\\[.*$", "$1"));
// output
//<STARTS WITH>
```